# The K-theoretic Farrell-Jones conjecture for cat(0) groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-k-theory

Is the fibered K-theoretic farrell-jones conjecture true for cat(0)-groups?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. More precisely, both the L-theory and K-theory Farrell-Jones conjectures with coefficients in any additive category have recently been proved for CAT(0) groups:

- Arthur Bartels, Wolfgang Lück, “The Borel Conjecture for hyperbolic and CAT(0)-groups”, Annals of Mathematics 175 (2012), 631–689, http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2012.175.2.5
- Christian Wegner, “The K-theoretic Farrell-Jones conjecture for CAT(0)-groups”, http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3349, to appear in Proceedings of the AMS.

In Arthur Bartels, Holger Reich, “Coefficients for the Farrell-Jones Conjecture”, Advances in Mathematics 209:1 (2007), 337–362, it is proved that *“with coefficients is stronger than fibered,”* see Corollary 4.3 and Remark 4.4 on page 346.

[Edited to clarify the relation between the “with coefficients” and “fibered” versions of the Farrell-Jones conjectures.]

Comment: But also they proved the fibered version?

Comment: Yes, see the paragraph I added above.

Comment: You are welcome, Luis!
And thanks a lot, Dan! Finally, right?